# dbus error on 14.04 after system is left idle for a few hours

Tags: ssd

I did a clean install of 14.04 on a crucial M4 64gb ssd.  The system boots in less than 30 seconds now! but.. when I leave it idle for a few hours and log back in nothing works ..  if I do a simple command like df ..I get a dbus error message. I also have a toshiba sata disk mounted for general storage since the ssd is so small .. nothing appears to be damaged when I reboot but it is extremely annoying .. any ideas on how to correct this will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the dbus error? Are there any errors in `/var/log/kern.log`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with M4 SSD.
I did a firmware update to 070H version see
http://forum.crucial.com/t5/Solid-State-Drives-SSD/Crucial-m4-SSD-firmware-07MH-for-mSATA-and-070H-for-2-5-quot/td-p/123930/page/22.
Upoad crucial-m4-070h-07-00.iso file, create a bootable USB key using UNetbootin and follow instructions.

No data lost on SSD.